# method of animating the webkit gradient using either css3 or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webkit

Basically I have set up a CSS3 gradient and would like to transition one of its colours to be larger on hover but im unsure how to achieve this.

My fiddle at the moment goes a little crazy on hover then kind of sizes to the correct size, I would rather the transition be a lot smoother with the blue area just growing instead of flying off the page. If anyone could offer some advice that would be great.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VQaGh/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to transition the `background-position`, just the `background-size` in this case - like this http://jsfiddle.net/VQaGh/4/

And why are you using the ancient webkit syntax? See [proper syntax](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-images/#linear-gradients).

Also, you could check this [animated gradients demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/2771602) I did a while ago.

Comment: Hey this is great, how can I make this smoothly transition back to its original size? At the moment it just jumps back?

Comment: You need to also explicitly set a `background-size` on `.outer-before` - see http://jsfiddle.net/VQaGh/6/